# Specifying valid "ranges" for batch values requests

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using the Google Sheets API quickstart for Python. I'm trying to pull multiple cells, just one cell at a time, from the google sheets api and plug each value into a text document. I've been doing this with `spreadsheets().values().get()`, but I'm hitting the API too much and the `batchGet()` method seems like it would be better. I read through the Google Sheets API v4 but was unable to find the correct formatting for the `ranges` parameter on `spreadsheets().values().batchGet()`. According to the docs, it appears that it takes an array of strings, or possibly a JSON object, but there's no example of the format in the docs (In fact, it says `// TODO`!). Does anyone know the correct format? I've tried:

```
spreadsheetId = 098217340987123049817235blahblahblah
ranges = ["A100:A100, "B100:B100"]
spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=ranges)
```

and

```
spreadsheetId = 098217340987123049817235blahblahblah
ranges = ["A100:A100"]
spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=ranges)
```

and just a string to be sure

```
spreadsheetId = 098217340987123049817235blahblahblah
ranges = "A100:A100"
spreadsheets().values().batchGet(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, ranges=ranges)
```

Each of these returns `[]`.

When I use `spreadsheets().values().get()` and `ranges="A100:A100`, function returns `[['cellvalue']]`, so I know there's data there.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You may check in this [link](https://github.com/levifussell/TYR/blob/53346fec334c5d712b51d2fe5e608daf3e2bdde5/GoogleSheetsAPI/quickstart.py) the sample code in using `batchGet`.

```
spreadsheetId = '1SizdeufKaODnq3WMV3T3uS2W47v4mZJeqYg2J1MiP9k'
rangeName = 'Sheet1!A2:A'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
```

Since `ranges` is the [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) of the values to retrieve, this is a string like `Sheet1!A1:B2` that refers to a group of cells in the spreadsheet, and is typically used in formulas.

For example, valid ranges are:

- `Sheet1!A1:B2` refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of Sheet1.
- `Sheet1!A:A` refers to all the cells in the first column of Sheet1.
- `Sheet1!1:2` refers to the all the cells in the first two rows of Sheet1.
- `Sheet1!A5:A` refers to all the cells of the first column of Sheet 1, from row 5 onward.
- `A1:B2` refers to the first two cells in the top two rows of the first visible sheet.
- `Sheet1` refers to all the cells in Sheet1.

Named ranges are also supported. When a named range conflicts with a sheet's name, the named range is preferred.

If the sheet name has spaces or starts with a bracket, surround the sheet name with single quotes (`'`), e.g `'Sheet One'!A1:B2`. For simplicity, it is safe to always surround the sheet name with single quotes.