# How to separate multiple columns from a range in an array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of data in a Google Sheet and I want to store that data into an array using the app script. At the moment I can bring in the data easily enough and put it into an array with this code:

```
  var sheetData = sheet.getSheetByName('Fruit').getRange('A1:C2').getValues()
```

However, this puts each row into an array. For example, [[Apple,Red,Round],[Banana,Yellow,Long]].

How can I arrange the array by columns so it would look: [[Apple,Banana],[Red,Yellow],[Round,Long]].

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to transpose the array. You can create a function

```
function transpose(data) {

return (data[0] || []).map (function (col , colIndex) {
    return data.map (function (row) {
      return row[colIndex];
      });
    });
 }
```

and then pass the values obtained by .getValues() to that function..

```
var sheetData = transpose(sheet.getSheetByName('Fruit').getRange('A1:C2').getValues())
```

and check the log. See if that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Sheets API, which allows you to specify the primary dimension of the response. To do so, first you must [enable the API and the advanced service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

To acquire values most efficiently, use the [`spreadsheets.values`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/#rest-resource-v4spreadsheetsvalues) endpoints, either [`get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) or [`batchGet`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) as appropriate. You are able to supply optional arguments to both calls, and one of which controls the orientation of the response:

```
const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const valService = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values;
const asColumn2D = { majorDimension: SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS };
const asRow2D = { majorDimension: SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS }; // this is the default

var sheet = wb.getSheetByName("some name");
var rgPrefix = "'" + sheet.getName() + "'!";

// spreadsheetId, range string, {optional arguments}
var single = valService.get(wb.getId(), rgPrefix + "A1:C30");
var singleAsCols = valService.get(wb.getId(), rgPrefix + "A1:C30", asColumn2D);

// spreadsheetId, {other arguments}
var batchAsCols = valService.batchGet(wb.getId(), {
  ranges: [
    rgPrefix + "A1:C30",
    rgPrefix + "J8",
    ...
  ],
  majorDimension: SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS
});
console.log({rowResp: single, colResp: singleAsCols, batchResponse: batchAsCols});
```

The reply will either be a [`ValueRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) (using `get`) or an object wrapping several `ValueRange`s (if using `batchGet`). You can access the data (if any was present) at the `ValueRange`'s `values` property. Note that trailing blanks are omitted.

You can find more information in the [Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values), and other relevant Stack Overflow questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539530/specifying-valid-ranges-for-batch-values-requests).